# How to block specific port with iptables

Tags: security, iptables, tcp, docker-registry

I have a service running (docker registry) on my debian server at port 5000. I would like to restrict access to that to specific IP, so I've created a file with rules (1.2.3.4 is my trusted IP)

```
*filter
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 --source 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

then i've used a command to apply these rules to iptables

```
sudo iptables-restore < myfile
```

so the result of command sudo iptables -L is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  1.2.3.4              anywhere             tcp dpt:5000
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Then i'm checking if port 5000 is reachable from internet (from my another server)

```
nc -zv 5.6.7.8 5000
```

and the result is [... ***5000 (?) open***]
My question is why ? These rules are so straightforward, why can i access service that is at port 5000 ?
Even if I keep just one rule (**-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DROP**), I can still access to that port.

Edit 1:
@A.B you're right. Now I can see  also docker's rules.

```
sudo iptables-save -c
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Thu Feb 13 15:21:42 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[39755:1536013] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[40:2500] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
[33:1824] -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Feb 13 15:21:42 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Thu Feb 13 15:21:42 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[0:0] -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Feb 13 15:21:42 2020
```

So now the question is how to add DROP rule to nat table? I've added a rule according to docker docs

```
sudo iptables -t nat -N DOCKER-USER
sudo iptables -t nat -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j RETURN
```

but no effect.

Edit2:
Finally! I've found an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462706/block-docker-port-and-access-it-to-few-ip-addresses

This solves the problem.

```
-I FORWARD 1 -d 172.17.0.2 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DROP
```

Comment: Just in case... what is the IP of your "another server" ? Isn't it that trusted one :) ?

Comment: Docker creates forwarding rules. So it forwards/nats it before INPUT takes place.

Comment: If you type the right command to see the iptables rules: `iptables-save -c` you'll discover there are many more.

Comment: @KamilJ it is not trusted one :)

Comment: @A.B you're right. Now I can see  also docker's rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your rules to the Docker chain.
To do this create the following file:

```
*filter
-I DOCKER -i [interface] -s 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
-I DOCKER 3 -i [interface] -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

This will deny any packets coming in to docker registry, except from 1.2.3.4
If you want to modify the rules and behaviour remember to change the metric accordingly.
Following link will provide further information for you:
https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: According to docs, firstly I've tried to add rule to DOCKER-USER chain. Result is "Chain 'DOCKER-USER' does not exist", same for DOCKER chain. Then I've create it using -N option, still no luck.

Comment: Ok this is a strange problem. is your docker service running? Does it work with the usual "iptables" command. Because i actually tested the rules provided in my answer and they worked out.

Comment: Thank you for help, please see my edit2 to see the solution.